# Disable update content_types when running Django's ./manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django

My project is am using Multiple Data Base to manage the Auth , content type information and Project App.

My Database Settings :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'test_default',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_auth_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
```

I have a router to manage for read and write

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == "auth" or model._meta.app_label == "sessions" or model._meta.app_label == "contenttypes":
        return "auth_db"
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == "auth" or model._meta.app_label == "sessions" or model._meta.app_label == "contenttypes":
        return "auth_db"
    return None

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):

    return  True
```

When ever i do syncdb all app content types are get updated in "auth_db". I want to stop this and sync with "default" database. So that all table will create and update only in the default DB.

When the Project run it will use read and write based on the router config.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed it by Updating the write funcfion

```
def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in ("sessions",) :
        return "auth_db"
    return "default"
```

So the the syncdb will not write any data to the "auth" and "contenttypes"